# Java instance type with generic version 8 vs 17

Tags: java, generics, collections, language-lawyer

As per Java Generic and Collections by Maurice Naftalin, in below options-

1. obj instanceof List
2. obj instanceof List<?>
3. obj instanceof List<? extends Object>

1st and 2nd is permitted but 3rd is not which works fine in java 8(version "1.8.0_321"). Option 1 and 2 compile and option 3 gives compile error.
But 3rd option work fine with java 17(version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS). Could you please help me understand why its working in java 17.
sample code which I am trying -

```
var a = List.of(2,3,4,5,23);
var b = a instanceof List<? extends Object>;
return b;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Prior to Java 16, the only purpose of `instanceof` was to check whether a referenced object is assignable to the specified type and since type erasure prevents from checking whether an object truly is assignable to a parameterized type, it made no sense to allow an expression pretending that such a test was possible.

The only thing which could be tested, was whether the object is an instance of `List` and hence, it was only allowed to write `… instanceof List` or `… instanceof List<?>`, as neither pretends to test the list’s element type.

Starting with Java 16 (available as preview since 14), `instanceof` allows to declare a new variable of the specified type.

For example:

```java
public void someMethod(Iterable<String> i) {
    if(i instanceof List<String> l) {
        if(l.isEmpty()) return;
        // optimized List processing
    } else {
        // generic iterable processing
    }
}
```

which is equivalent to

```java
public void someMethod(Iterable<String> i) {
    if(i instanceof List<String>) {
        List<String> l = (List<String>)i;
        if(l.isEmpty()) return;
        // optimized List processing
    } else {
        // generic iterable processing
    }
}
```

For the declaration of a new variable, it would be impractical to be limited to raw types or wildcard types. Therefore, it is now allowed to specify actual type arguments, which are relevant to the implied variable declaration and assignment. Since the element type still can’t be checked, you are only allowed to specify types to which the compile-time source type could be cast without an *unchecked* cast.

So, the following would not be valid

```java
Iterable<?> i = null;
boolean b = i instanceof List<String>;
```

because you can’t safely cast from `Iterable<?>` to `List<String>`.

In your example, `var a = List.of(2,3,4,5,23);` declares `a` as `List<Integer>`, hence, `a instanceof List<? extends Object>` is valid because `List<Integer>` is assignable to `List<? extends Object>` (even without a cast).

Of course, specifying element types which are not checked is only useful if you declare a variable like in the first example. But the Java language follows the principle of not adding extra rules just because some construct is less useful than the other. Therefore, you can now always specify actual type arguments to `instanceof` following the same rules, whether you declare a variable or not.

This feature is called [Pattern Matching](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Ebriangoetz/amber/pattern-match.html) as it is considered a special case of a broader concept which Java is heading for. In JDK 17, there’s a similar feature for `switch` available as preview.

See also [§14.30. Patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.30) in the Java Language Specification.